# Intellij issue Failed to load script defintions by org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.GradleScriptDefintionsContributor

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I created a spring boot kotlin project on the spring boot generator page. When I install the project in Intellij none of the dependencies load and I see the error:

```
Failed to load script definitions by org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.GradleScriptDefinitionsContributor
```

I have gradle and kotlin installed.

Comment: Do you have some more error message? With only this little information I'm not able to help you

Comment: no just the imports in class files are all red because the dependencies are not loaded. './gradlew build' completes successfully.

Comment: Which IntelliJ Version are you using?

Comment: Ultimate 2019.1

Comment: I tried the same and have no issues. Maybe you should try again or ask the support https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?intellij-idea

Comment: Thanks, i'll try another computer.

Comment: Try to reinstall IDE from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html and delete IDE folders to start with all the defaults (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Comment: Had same issue. Restarting & invalidating caches worked for me.

Comment: I updated and restarted IntelliJ but this error is not going away. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65626029/failed-to-load-script-defintions-by-org-jetbrains-kotlin-idea-core-script-gradle